# Hub site Navigation customization - Share Point online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, online

I have an hubsite where i wanted to insert a huge name in hubsite navigation, unfortunately that is eating up space from navigation bar and other teams are getting hidden from navigation.

What is the way i can toogle size or font or the navigation ribbon ?

PS: I am not Farm admin  but i am site admin.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid that is not possible.

The settings you can set for navigation are all listed here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca

Also, customization for modern navigation is currently [not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites#whats-not-supported-on-modern-team-sites), so custom solution is not an option either.